# crear Zip de plugin | wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hola ya desarrollé un plugin para wordpress, pero quisiera saber que procedimiento o que documentos debe de contener el .zip para poder instalarlo

porque al momento de intentar subirlo me marca éste error

```
PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

Alguien que me pueda asesorar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomado de SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771578/wordpress-theme-upload-error-pclzip-err-bad-format

El problema es generalmente que estás usando un tipo de compresión distinto a `zip`, por ejemplo `rar`.

Otros usuarios reportaron que su archivo zip contenía otro archivo zip.

Una solución alternativa es subir los archivos directamente por FTP al directorio adecuado: /wp-content/plugins

Comment: Sin duda creo que ese es el problema y haré lo del FTP

Comment: Quedo pendiente.

Comment: Pero por los archivos que lleva dentro, no hay algún requerimiento?, en caso de querer empaquetarlo

Comment: No, ninguno....

Comment: Ok, entonces intentaré empaquetarlo, ya que cómo comentaste, al comprimirlo utilizaba el formato RAR

Comment: Shaz, tengo que decirte que me ayudaste demasiado, ese era el problema, cambie el formato y ya se puede subir :O. Gracias